# What computing knowledge do you need to solve chess?

Tags: software, computer-chess, game-complexity

I am a 2300-rated FM in chess. Sometimes I want to know to know is this: what computing knowledge do you need to solve the game of chess? Does anyone know precisely?

Comment: It's more a matter of the computational complexity of the problem than chess knowledge.  There are so many possible positions that it is unlikely that chess will ever be solved.

Comment: Even if you solved it, where would you store the data for all of those positions? You'd be forced to "forget it"